Effects of Gravity on Glide Ratio
I know that the weight of an aircraft has no effect on the glide ratio. However, gravity affects not just weight but also downward acceleration, which presumably should have some sort of effect on the behaviour of a craft. Thus the question: how does a craft's glide ratio scale with a planet's gravity (assuming other environmental parameters like atmospheric density, temperature &c. are the same for the sake of the case)?

In a glide, the sink speed constant. Hence, the downward acceleration is zero...

Let's hope that space.stackexchange.com finds something suitable to link to here!

"gravity affects not just weight but also downward acceleration"  What do you mean by this?  Weight IS downward acceleration as far as I understand it.

@MikeB A litre-sized cube of tungsten has about 20 times the weight of a same-sized cube of ice, but has the same downward acceleration (about 9.8m/s²) in free fall (which is then reduced by air resistance, if there is an atmosphere in the environment). But a litre-sized ice cube on Mars (where gravity is lower) would have a not only a reduced weight, but also only have a modest downward acceleration of about 3.7 m/s².

@vicky_molokh  I still don't get what you are talking about. The change of weight, and the change of acceleration are identical, because they are both effectively measures of the same thing, ie the change in gravity.

If there is no gravity, there is nothing to worry.

@MikeB I apologise, I don't understand how are they identical. Could you elaborate using the example provided (two cubes of different mass but identical size [ice and tungsten], and two planets with different gravities [Terra and Mars], with the corresponding results of weight and acceleration for the four possible combinations)?

From this answer: glide angle tan $\bar\gamma$ = $C_D/C_L$. The weight, density, speed and wing area have all been divided out.

So on a planet where the two lift&drag equations are valid, the glide ratio is purely proportional to the lift/drag ratio - gravitation, no matter what magnitude, has been divided out.

The local gravity affects an aircraft through its weight -- nothing else.
If the weight (or gravity) would change, the speed for best glide (best L/D) would be different -- but the glide slope would remain the same.
That said, the atmosphere of this other planet would also likely have a different density (and also composition and even viscosity) that would have a greater effect.
The density would also change the speed for best L/D, but not the value of best L/D.
A different gas would first change the Reynolds number, which might change the drag behavior slightly -- and slightly change the L/D.
A sufficiently different gas would have a different speed of sound -- which could mean that compressibility effects would become important at a much lower speed.  However, temperature also affects this and is probably easier to imagine a very cold atmosphere having a more straightforward effect.

I don't know, but I suspect, that a wide range of atmospheric densities and gravitational accelerations are possible, and that there is considerable latitude for them to vary independently (consider just Venus, Earth and Mars.) If so, I further suspect that there could be some significant differences in Reynolds number at flying speed, leading to something more than just a slight change in L/D (but +1 for being the only person so far to mention the Reynolds number.)

On Earth, its relatively small variations in gravity have no effect on the glide ratio.
But you're correct in that a major change in gravity will, of course, affect aircraft flyability. But it will not do so by changing the L/D ratio directly. Instead, a major increase in gravity (e.g. 10x) will require much more lift to be produced.
So, flight will require much more power - 10x gravity means 10x lift, means 10x drag, means 10x thrust to overcome it, and thus 10x the fuel consumption per mile.
If air density is unchanged, this will require wings that normally have a higher lift coefficient, which means much more camber, a thicker wing, and/or a higher angle of attack. Any of these greatly degrade the L/D ratio. Flight range will be shorter (about 10x), or some speed might be traded for range, e.g. planes will be 2x slower and fly 1/5 as far.
If air density is increased by the same factor as gravity, drag will increase greatly. But powered flight will remain possible at the same lift coefficient, and with engines of comparable construction. It will be much slower, however, by a factor of about 3x. Range will also decrease, but not as much, if lower speeds are acceptable.

Flight on Mars is more difficult than on Earth because of the thinner atmosphere, but was possible while there was an unbroken helicopter on the planet.  I would think an increase gravity would likely increase atmospheric density so as to make flight easier, or allow lighter-than-air craft to be smaller.

@supercat Air density isn't directly proportional to gravity; Venus has less gravity than Earth, but a much denser atmosphere. With a dense atmosphere, flight will be easier. But more gravity is always worse for flight; it's more lift to produce, and thus more drag.

Doubling gravity while keeping the same thickness of atmopsphere would double atmospheric pressure and thus atmospheric density.  I think that if atmospheric thickness is limited by the boil-off of gas into space, having stronger gravity will allow for a thicker atmosphere.  If an atmosphere is thin because there was never enough gas to surround a planet or moon, stronger gravity would lead to a thinner atmosphere.  If there's too little gravity to maintain an atmosphere, gliding will be impossible no matter how little lift would be required.

I will analyse only the second part of your question since the first part has already been discussed in the other very good answers.

However, gravity affects not just weight but also downward acceleration, which presumably should have some sort of effect on the behaviour of a craft.

Correct:
On a glider you normally want to fly either maximising:

the range or
the time airborne.

To maximise:

the range, you have to fly at the best (highest) $L/D$;
to maximise the time, you have to fly at the best (lowest) sink rate.

Without entering in mathematical details, if we express lift and drag with the ubiquitous:
\begin{equation}
\left\{ \begin{aligned} 
  D=½\rho V^2 S C_d\\
  L=½\rho V^2 S C_l\\
  C_d=C_{d_{0}}+kC^2_l
\end{aligned} \right.
\end{equation}
we get that:

the speed for the best $L/D$ (max range) is $\sqrt{\frac{2W}{\rho S}\sqrt{\frac{k}{C_{d_{0}}}}}$
the speed for the best sink rate (max time) is $\sqrt{\frac{2W}{\rho S}\sqrt{\frac{k}{3C_{d_{0}}}}}$

Note how these two equations are very similar except for a "3" in the speed for the best sink rate (which is therefore 76% the speed for the best $L/D$): a sailplane pilot will typically fly at the speed for best $L/D$ (max range) when looking for a thermal and then will decelerate at the speed of best sink rate (max time) when inside a thermal.
To come at last to your question: the weight $W$ does have indeed a direct impact on those two speeds. If we bring our sailplane on a planet with half the earth gravity then its glide ratio would be the same but the speed for the best glide ratio would be 30% smaller. Obviously half gravity would also have an indirect impact on the aircraft itself, as already explained for example by Therac's answer.
